# Npm install does not work

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

I have a problem with my npm. This is my error:

[image: screen cap of error message]

I try to uninstall nodejs and install it but my error stays, then I try the command npm install npm, Have the same error and `npm -v` does not work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delete `%APPDATA%\npm` and reinstall node.

Answer (score -1):

package `semver` is missing.
running `npm install semver` and try again

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back this up? I hope you didn't down vote Anh just on guess, assuming it was you that down voted him.

Comment: @Don if `npm -v` does not work because of a missing package, `npm install` won't work. Furthermore `npm install semver` installs a package locally, whereas `npm` is installed globally.